# Escaping quotes using jackson-dataformat-xml

Tags: java, xml, jackson, escaping, jackson-dataformat-xml

I need help with `jackson-dataformat-xml`. I need to serialize `List<String>` using `XmlMapper` into the xml with encoding the quotes `"` → `&quot;`.

But after serializing `XmlMapper` encodes all other special symbols (`<`, `>`, `&` etc) but ignores quotes (`'` and `"`) at all... If I encode the string manually before serialization, the content messes up because `&quot;` has `'&'` inside and it's serializing as `&amp;quot;` instead of course.

Maybe anyone knows how to make it work? 
Also, is there a way as work-around to disable auto special symbols encoding on the `List<String>` field using `@JacksonRawValue` or something like that? This annotation works great on simple (non-arrays) fields but not gonna work properly on `List<String>`.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of what you serialize, what you execute and what serialized form do you get?

Comment: Just trying to put in here in code tags, so it can be formatted well ..

Comment: @aprodymov as you're probably understood, SO does not support multi-line code formatting in the comments :) But I've got the idea. What values do you put into your `list`, what value is generated and what do you expect?

Comment: I put something like that. aa&c"bbb. 
Generated: aa&amp;c"bbb. But I expect aa&amp;c&quot;bbb.

Comment: If I encode use StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(value) and then serialize it. It goes into aa&amp;amp;c&amp;quot;bbb. Because it encodes already encoded values with & inside - you understand

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how the problem was solved. I used woodbox Stax2 extension. 
This helped a lot.
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/issues/75

```
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper(module);
xmlMapper.getFactory().getXMLOutputFactory().setProperty(XMLOutputFactory2.P_TEXT_ESCAPER, 
new CustomXmlEscapingWriterFactory());
```

And here's the factory.

```
public class CustomXmlEscapingWriterFactory implements EscapingWriterFactory {
public Writer createEscapingWriterFor(final Writer out, String enc) {
    return new Writer(){
        @Override
        public void write(char[] cbuf, int off, int len) throws IOException {
            String val = "";
            for (int i = off; i < len; i++) {
                val += cbuf[i];
            }
            String escapedStr =  StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(val);
            out.write(escapedStr);
        }

        @Override
        public void flush() throws IOException {
            out.flush();
        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException {
            out.close();
        }
      };
    }

    public Writer createEscapingWriterFor(OutputStream out, String enc) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("not supported");
    }
}
```

Comment: Omg, I've spent some hours of finding how to implement `EscapingWriterFactory`, but you've already done it. Perfect! Congratulations. I think I will upload the whole working project to GitHub, but already in the morning. Have to sleep for today.

Comment: @DmitriyPopov, actually there was a bug, where I used  `StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml` on the whole `cbuf` in my first attempt. So there were a lot of junk after serialization. 
Only from 0 to len should be used. But maybe some trick with `off ` also needed: it's unused at the moment and I'm still not sure if it can cause any problems in some cases. All in all now it's working how I need.
Thanks.

Comment: Oh, we should start from `off` not from zero, seems.